# Lazyloading html at the byte level

Tags: html, lazy-loading

I'm aware of things like infinite scroll,where I can load the (n+1)th page of HTML and throw it into the current document, but are there any methods for loading a *single* very large html document in chunks and displaying those chunks as they arrive?

I'm imagining a 'loader' html document, with suitable javascript to make an `accept-ranges` type query of the super-large html, collect the first 50 Kb, pass all the complete html elements to the page DOM, keep the rest in the buffer while the next 50 Kb are requested. This process would repeat until the page was fully loaded.

This kind of functionality could be entirely provided by a browser which displayed page content which has finished downloading - but I'm not sure how many can do this and remain responsive (ie. usable) while the rest arrives.

Any thoughts welcome! Thanks